# Execute Multiple Informix SQL queries in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, informix

I am trying to execute multiple Informix SQL queries in ASP.NET.
When I execute these 4 queries with or without semicolons I got syntax error like this one:

```
ERROR [42000] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]A syntax error has occurred.
```

Is it possible to execute 4 queries one by one in separate OdbcCommand commands since I am using temporary tables for my final SQL command or all in one command?

This is the method that I have created:

```
        public SumarneDjelatnosti GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList(String appid, String oper, Int16 godina)
        {
            //METODA
            // TODO: unit test GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList

            SvcActContext sac = null;

            sac = InitCtx("GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList");

            if (appid == null) { appid = ""; }

            oper = OperAlter(appid, sac, oper);

            SumarneDjelatnosti popis = new SumarneDjelatnosti();

            if (!SvcAccessAuth.AccessGranted(appid, sac))
            {
                popis.Odgovor = "Neovlašten pristup.";

                popis.OdgovorStatus = -100;

                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "UnauthorizedUse", oper, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), popis.Odgovor, 200);

                return popis;
            }

            String dsnc = AppGlobals.DSNd;

            String opmbo = oper.Trim();
            String ust;

            EPonudaOperToken tok = new EPonudaOperToken();

            tok = _GetEPonudaSekOperOvl(appid, sac, oper);

            if (tok.OdgovorStatus < 0)
            {
                popis.Odgovor = tok.Odgovor;
                popis.OdgovorStatus = tok.OdgovorStatus;

                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Error", oper, null, String.Format("GetEPonudaSekOperOvl: {0}, {1}", popis.OdgovorStatus, popis.Odgovor), null, 200);

                return popis;
            }
            ust = tok.DavzuSif;

            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Begin", opmbo, null, dsnc, null, 50);

            using (OdbcConnection ocn = new OdbcConnection(AppGlobals.OdbcCString(true)))
            {
                try
                {
                    ocn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    popis.Odgovor = "Pristup bazi podataka nije moguć.";

                    popis.OdgovorStatus = -101;

                    LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DbAccessError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                    return popis;
                }

                using (OdbcCommand dbcmd = ocn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    String first = "";
#if DEBUG
                    first = " first 25 ";
#endif
                    String sql = @"
                    select " + first + @" p.id, dj.sifra djsifra, dj.naziv djnaziv, 
                    sum((case
                    when r.krevet is null then r.brkrevk 
                    when r.brkrevk is null then r.krevet
                    else r.krevet+r.brkrevk
                    end)) br_kreveta, 
                    sum(r.mjesta) mjesta_bolnice,
                    sum(r.postup) br_postupaka, sum(r.sala) br_sala, 
                    round(sum(
                    (case 
                    when dj.sifra like '%1' then 1
                    else r.sati/40
                    end)
                    ),2)  ordinacija
                    FROM eponudesb p
                    right join radiliste  r on r.eponudesb_id = p.id
                    right join djelzz dj on dj.id = r.djelzz_id
                    where r.godina=2018  
                    and p.davzu_sif='004200420'
                    group by p.id, dj.sifra, dj.naziv
                    order by dj.sifra 
                    into temp djelatnost_izv_temp;

                    select " + first + @"djsifra, djnaziv, round(sum(ordinacija),2) 
                    suma_ordinacija from djelatnost_izv_temp
                    group by 1,2 into temp djelatnost_izv_sum_temp;

                    update djelatnost_izv_temp set 
                    ordinacija=(select suma_ordinacija 
                    from djelatnost_izv_sum_temp 
                    where djelatnost_izv_sum_temp.djsifra=djelatnost_izv_temp.djsifra );

                    select " + first + @"dj.sifra djsifra, dj.naziv djnaziv,
                    trim (g.sifra) ||'-'|| trim(s.sifspr) sprema, 
                    round(sum(t.sati/40),2) sati_spreme
                    FROM eponudesb p
                    left join radiliste  r on r.eponudesb_id = p.id
                    left join djelzz dj on dj.id = r.djelzz_id
                    left join timrad t on t.radiliste_id=r.id
                    left join djelponude dp on dp.id=t.djelponude_id
                    left join strspr s on s.id=dp.strspr_id
                    left join zdrdje z on z.id=dp.zdrdje_id
                    left join tipzdpon ti on ti.id=dp.tipzdpon_id
                    left join grtippon g on ti.grtippon_id=g.id
                    where r.godina=2018 
                    and p.davzu_sif='004200420'
                    group by dj.sifra, dj.naziv, s.sifspr, g.sifra
                    order by dj.sifra, sprema
                    into temp struc_sprem_izv_temp;

                    select " + first + @"d.djsifra djsifra, d.djnaziv djnaziv, 
                    d.br_kreveta br_kreveta,
                    d.mjesta_bolnice mjesta_bolnice,
                    d.br_postupaka br_postupaka,
                    d.br_sala br_sala, d.ordinacija ordinacija,
                    s.sprema naziv_sprema, s. sati_spreme sati_spreme
                    from struc_sprem_izv_temp s
                    left join djelatnost_izv_temp d on d.djsifra=s.djsifra;
                    ";

                    dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                    //dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@godina", OdbcType.Int).Value = godina;
                    //dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@davzu_sif", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ust;

                    try
                    {
                        using (OdbcDataReader dbReader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            List<DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv> itl = new List<DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv>();

                            while (dbReader.Read())
                            {
                                DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv pspi = new DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv();

                                pspi.SifraDjelatnosti = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader, "djsifra", "", true, false);
                                pspi.NazivDjelatnosti = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader, "djnaziv", "", true, false);
                                pspi.BrojKreveta = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "br_kreveta", (double)0);
                                pspi.BrojMjestaDnevneBolnice = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "mjesta_bolnice", (double)0);
                                pspi.BrojPostupakaHemodijalize = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "br_postupaka", (double)0);
                                pspi.BrojOperacijskihSala = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "br_sala", (double)0);
                                pspi.BrojOrdinacija = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "ordinacija", (double)0);
                                pspi.NazivStrucneSpreme = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader, "naziv_sprema", "", true, false);
                                pspi.SatiStrucneSpreme = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader, "sati_spreme", (double)0);

                                itl.Add(pspi);

                            }

                            if (itl.Count > 0)
                            {
                                popis.Lista = itl.ToArray();
                                popis.OdgovorStatus = popis.Lista.Length;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                popis.Odgovor = "";

                                popis.OdgovorStatus = 0;

                                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "NoRows", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), popis.Odgovor, 150);

                                return popis;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.";

                        popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                        LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                        return popis;
                    }
                }

                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Success", opmbo, null, dsnc, null, 100);

                return popis;
            }

        }
```

EDIT: When I execute those SQL commands in DBeaver script runs without errors. Is it possible to rewrite queries in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by calling each SQL query one by one. It is messy way to do it but it works. If anyone has better solution please submit.
This is the method:

```
    public SumarneDjelatnosti GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList(String appid, String oper, Int16 godina)
    {
        //METODA
        // TODO: unit test GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList

        SvcActContext sac = null;

        sac = InitCtx("GetEPonudeDjelatnostiSumarnoList");

        if (appid == null) { appid = ""; }

        oper = OperAlter(appid, sac, oper);

        SumarneDjelatnosti popis = new SumarneDjelatnosti();

        if (!SvcAccessAuth.AccessGranted(appid, sac))
        {
            popis.Odgovor = "Neovlašten pristup.";

            popis.OdgovorStatus = -100;

            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "UnauthorizedUse", oper, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), popis.Odgovor, 200);

            return popis;
        }

        String dsnc = AppGlobals.DSNd;

        String opmbo = oper.Trim();
        String ust;

        EPonudaOperToken tok = new EPonudaOperToken();

        tok = _GetEPonudaSekOperOvl(appid, sac, oper);

        if (tok.OdgovorStatus < 0)
        {
            popis.Odgovor = tok.Odgovor;
            popis.OdgovorStatus = tok.OdgovorStatus;

            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Error", oper, null, String.Format("GetEPonudaSekOperOvl: {0}, {1}", popis.OdgovorStatus, popis.Odgovor), null, 200);

            return popis;
        }
        ust = tok.DavzuSif;

        LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Begin", opmbo, null, dsnc, null, 50);

        using (OdbcConnection ocn = new OdbcConnection(AppGlobals.OdbcCString(true)))
        {
            try
            {
                ocn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                popis.Odgovor = "Pristup bazi podataka nije moguć.";

                popis.OdgovorStatus = -101;

                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DbAccessError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                return popis;
            }

            using (OdbcCommand dbcmd = ocn.CreateCommand())
            {
                String first = "";
#if DEBUG
                first = " first 25 ";
#endif
                String sql = @"
                select " + first + @" p.id, dj.sifra djsifra, dj.naziv djnaziv, 
                sum((case
                when r.krevet is null then r.brkrevk 
                when r.brkrevk is null then r.krevet
                else r.krevet+r.brkrevk
                end)) br_kreveta, 
                sum(r.mjesta) mjesta_bolnice,
                sum(r.postup) br_postupaka, sum(r.sala) br_sala, 
                round(sum(
                (case 
                when dj.sifra like '%1' then 1
                else r.sati/40
                end)
                ),2)  ordinacija
                FROM eponudesb p
                right join radiliste  r on r.eponudesb_id = p.id
                right join djelzz dj on dj.id = r.djelzz_id
                where r.godina=2018  
                and p.davzu_sif='004200420'
                group by p.id, dj.sifra, dj.naziv
                order by dj.sifra 
                into temp djelatnost_izv_temp;
                ";
                using (OdbcCommand dbcmd1 = ocn.CreateCommand())
                {                   
                    String sql1 = @"
                    select " + first + @"djsifra, djnaziv, round(sum(ordinacija),2) 
                    suma_ordinacija from djelatnost_izv_temp
                    group by 1,2 into temp djelatnost_izv_sum_temp;
                    ";
                    using (OdbcCommand dbcmd2 = ocn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        String sql2 = @"
                        update djelatnost_izv_temp set 
                        ordinacija=(select suma_ordinacija 
                        from djelatnost_izv_sum_temp 
                        where djelatnost_izv_sum_temp.djsifra=djelatnost_izv_temp.djsifra );
                        ";
                        using (OdbcCommand dbcmd3 = ocn.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            String sql3 = @"
                            select " + first + @"dj.sifra djsifra, dj.naziv djnaziv,
                            trim (g.sifra) ||'-'|| trim(s.sifspr) sprema, 
                            round(sum(t.sati/40),2) sati_spreme
                            FROM eponudesb p
                            left join radiliste  r on r.eponudesb_id = p.id
                            left join djelzz dj on dj.id = r.djelzz_id
                            left join timrad t on t.radiliste_id=r.id
                            left join djelponude dp on dp.id=t.djelponude_id
                            left join strspr s on s.id=dp.strspr_id
                            left join zdrdje z on z.id=dp.zdrdje_id
                            left join tipzdpon ti on ti.id=dp.tipzdpon_id
                            left join grtippon g on ti.grtippon_id=g.id
                            where r.godina=2018 
                            and p.davzu_sif='004200420'
                            group by dj.sifra, dj.naziv, s.sifspr, g.sifra
                            order by dj.sifra, sprema
                            into temp struc_sprem_izv_temp;
                            ";
                            using (OdbcCommand dbcmd4 = ocn.CreateCommand())
                            {
                                String sql4 = @"
                                select " + first + @"d.djsifra djsifra, d.djnaziv djnaziv, 
                                d.br_kreveta br_kreveta,
                                d.mjesta_bolnice mjesta_bolnice,
                                d.br_postupaka br_postupaka,
                                d.br_sala br_sala, d.ordinacija ordinacija,
                                s.sprema naziv_sprema, s. sati_spreme sati_spreme
                                from struc_sprem_izv_temp s
                                left join djelatnost_izv_temp d on d.djsifra=s.djsifra;
                                ";
                                dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                                dbcmd1.CommandText = sql1;
                                dbcmd2.CommandText = sql2;
                                dbcmd3.CommandText = sql3;
                                dbcmd4.CommandText = sql4;
                                //dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@godina", OdbcType.Int).Value = godina;
                                //dbcmd.Parameters.Add("@davzu_sif", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = ust;

                                try
                                {
                                    using (OdbcDataReader dbReader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                                    {
                                        List<DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv> itl = new List<DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv>();
                                    try
                                    {
                                        using (OdbcDataReader dbReader1 = dbcmd1.ExecuteReader())
                                        {
                                            try
                                            {
                                                using (OdbcDataReader dbReader2 = dbcmd2.ExecuteReader())
                                                {
                                                    try
                                                    {
                                                        using (OdbcDataReader dbReader3 = dbcmd3.ExecuteReader())
                                                        {
                                                            try
                                                            {
                                                                using (OdbcDataReader dbReader4 = dbcmd4.ExecuteReader())
                                                                {
                                                                    while (dbReader4.Read())
                                                                    {
                                                                        DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv pspi = new DjelatnostiSumarnoIzv();

                                                                        pspi.SifraDjelatnosti = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader4, "djsifra", "", true, false);
                                                                        pspi.NazivDjelatnosti = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader4, "djnaziv", "", true, false);
                                                                        pspi.BrojKreveta = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "br_kreveta", (double)0);
                                                                        pspi.BrojMjestaDnevneBolnice = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "mjesta_bolnice", (double)0);
                                                                        pspi.BrojPostupakaHemodijalize = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "br_postupaka", (double)0);
                                                                        pspi.BrojOperacijskihSala = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "br_sala", (double)0);
                                                                        pspi.BrojOrdinacija = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "ordinacija", (double)0);
                                                                        pspi.NazivStrucneSpreme = DBHelper.GetOdbcString(dbReader4, "naziv_sprema", "", true, false);
                                                                        pspi.SatiStrucneSpreme = DBHelper.GetOdbcNum(dbReader4, "sati_spreme", (double)0);

                                                                        itl.Add(pspi);

                                                                        }

                                                                            if (itl.Count > 0)
                                                                            {
                                                                                popis.Lista = itl.ToArray();
                                                                                popis.OdgovorStatus = popis.Lista.Length;
                                                                            }
                                                                            else
                                                                            {
                                                                                popis.Odgovor = "";

                                                                                popis.OdgovorStatus = 0;

                                                                                LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "NoRows", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), popis.Odgovor, 150);

                                                                                return popis;
                                                                            }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                                {
                                                                    popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.[4.]";

                                                                    popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                                                                    LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                                                                    return popis;
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                                        {
                                                            popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.[3.]";

                                                            popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                                                            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                                                            return popis;
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                }
                                                catch (Exception ex)
                                                {
                                                    popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.[Update]";

                                                    popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                                                    LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                                                    return popis;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.[2.]";

                                            popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                                            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                                            return popis;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    popis.Odgovor = "Podatke nije moguće učitati.";

                                    popis.OdgovorStatus = -102;

                                    LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "DataReadError", opmbo, null, popis.OdgovorStatus.ToString(), ex.Message, 200);

                                    return popis;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            LogSvcEvent(appid, sac, "Success", opmbo, null, dsnc, null, 100);

            return popis;
        }

    }
```